# What is use and Benefit of Yii FormElement Template

Tags: php, yii2

I am having doubt out some thing in Yii framework. What is benefit of giving like this in yii2 `['template' => '<div class="form-group">{input}<label class="control-label">{label}</label></div>']`

For  Eg:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'rememberMe',['template' => '<div class="form-group">{input}<label class="control-label">{label}</label></div>'])
->checkbox() ?>
```

I can do it in normal way.Why i want write code for it..

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: i want to know benefit of giving like this `['template' => '<div class="form-group">{input}<label class="control-label">{label}</label></div>']`

Comment: Please explain more precisely what you are trying to achieve. Also the code in your example is wrong.

Comment: i can write my template like this `<div><?= $form->field($model, 'rememberMe')->checkbox()</div>` but In yii2  Refer this like `<?= $form->field($model, 'rememberMe')
->checkbox(
['template' => '<div class="form-group">{input}<label class="control-label">{label}</label></div>']
) ?>` what is the benefit of write my template in yii2

Comment: Where it's taken from?

Comment: from http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-bootstrap-activefield.html

Answer (score 1):

The default template is :

```
'{label}\n{input}\n{hint}\n{error}'
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activefield.html#$template-detail

If you want to custom the position of the label, input or error, it's necessary to edit it.

You can also remove the label for example.

Answer (score 0):

There is no benefit in your example. Of course your example comes from nothing and has nothing to do with how the template field is suppose to be used (the page that you link has nothing to do again with your example) but you are right in your example there is no benefit.

However the option is there when you want to use it the proper way.